# How to use user input to end a program?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I am writing a program that converts Millimeters to Inches. Basically its a continuous loop that allows you to keep putting in numbers and get the correct converted measurement. I want to put an IF statement that will allow the user to type "end" to end the program instead of converting more units of measurement. How would I go about making this work? What python code allows you to exit a written program and can be used in an IF statement?

```
convert = float(25.4)
while True:
    print("*******MM*******")
    MM = float(input())
    Results = float(MM/convert)
    print("*****Inches*****")
    print("%.3f" % Results)
    print("%.4f" % Results)
    print("%.5f" % Results)
```

Comment: You can use a `break` statement to stop a `while` loop.

Comment: are you trying to do something like `if ... sys.exit(1)`?

Comment: Your code already works. When I enter `end`, the program ends. Mind you, it throws a `NameError` before terminating, but it _does_ end :-)

Comment: Please don't change the code in the question to an answer. If you do, the answers become useless.

Answer (score 5):

To end the loop, you can use a `break` statement. This can be used inside an `if` statement, since `break` only looks at loops, not conditionals. So:

```
if user_input == "end":
    break
```

Notice how I used `user_input`, not `MM`? That's because your code has a minor problem right now: you're calling `float()` before you ever check what the user typed. Which means if they type "end", you'll call `float("end")` and get an exception. Change your code to something like this:

```
user_input = input()
if user_input == "end":
    break
MM = float(user_input)
# Do your calculations and print your results
```

One more improvement you can make: if you want the user to be able to type "END" or "End" or "end", you can use the `lower()` method to convert the input to lowercase before comparing it:

```
user_input = input()
if user_input.lower() == "end":
    break
MM = float(user_input)
# Do your calculations and print your results
```

Make all those changes, and your program will work the way you want it to.

Comment: He's using Python 3. `input` in Python 3 works the way `raw_input` does in Python 2.

Comment: Thanks: I missed that. Fixed my answer to reflect this.

Comment: you should also recommend trimming whitespace from the input, in case the user accidentally hit the spacebar before or after "end"

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#iter) with a sentinel:

```
convert = float(25.4)
for i in iter(input, 'end'):
    print("*******MM*******")
    try:
        MM = float(i)
    except ValueError:
        print("can't convert {}".format(i)) 
    else:
        Results = float(MM/convert)
        print("*****Inches*****")
        print("%.3f" % Results)
        print("%.4f" % Results)
        print("%.5f" % Results)
```

This way, [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#iter) calls [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input) and stores the return value of it in `i` until `i == 'end'`.

Note that you probably want some error checking in case the user enters a non numeric value like in the example above.

Comment: The question is tagged with py3x, there's no `raw_input` in py3x.

Comment: I think he's doing this in Python 3. Didn't they rename `raw_input()` to `input()` in Python 3?

Comment: Personally I think it's a bit sloppy to do it this way. For example, what if the user types "End" or " end" or "end "?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `break` to break out of the loop.

```
MM = input()
if MM == "end":
    break
```

Comment: What if I changed the code to convert=float(25.4)
while True:
    print("*******MM*******")
    MM=float(input())
    Results=float(MM/convert)
    print("*****Inches*****")
    print("%.3f" % Results)
    print("%.4f" % Results)
    print("%.5f" % Results)

Comment: @Vyktor how would I make it so MM isnt a float but is still able to be converted?

Comment: You can convert it to whatever type, e.g. `int()` or `str()`.

Answer (score 2):

To end loop you could use [`break` statement](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). You could also take advantage of fact that [`ValueError`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) is [raised](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) if non convertible value is issued:

```
convert = float(25.4)
while True:
    print("*******MM*******")
    MM = input()
    try:
        MM = float(MM)
    except ValueError:
        break
    
    Results = float(MM/convert)
    print("*****Inches*****")
    print("%.3f" % Results)
    print("%.4f" % Results)
    print("%.5f" % Results)
```

Result:

```
$ ./convert 
Convert MM to Inches
*******MM*******
exit
$
```

---

Or if you want to exit only on string `exit` and go to next loop if error occurs, nice way would be:

```
MM = input()
if MM == 'exit':
    break

try:
    MM = float(MM)
except ValueError:
    print('I\'m sorry {} isn\'t a valid value'.format(MM))
    continue # Next iteration
```

---

Or you could make it *"linuxy"* you can wait until [`Ctrl+C` (Keyboard interrupt)](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) is pressed   and handle it gracefully:

```
try:
    # Whole program goes here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Bye bye')
```

Which will go like this (`^C` means sending `Ctrl+C`):

```
$ ./convert 
Convert MM to Inches
*******MM*******
^CBye bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing for `MM` after it is input by the user could work. You use the keyword `break` to break out of the loop. Your example, after the minor additions is as follows.

```
convert = float(25.4)
while True:
    print("*******MM*******")
    MM = input()
    if MM == 'end':
        break
    Results = float(MM)/convert
    print("*****Inches*****")
    print("%.3f" % Results)
    print("%.4f" % Results)
    print("%.5f" % Results)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os

convert = float(25.4)
while True:
    print("*******MM*******")
    MM = input()
    if MM.lower() in ('end', 'quit'):
        os._exit(1)
    MM = float(MM)
    Results = float(MM/convert)
    print("*****Inches*****")
    print("%.3f" % Results)
    print("%.4f" % Results)
    print("%.5f" % Results)
```

or

```
convert = float(25.4)
while True:
    print("*******MM*******")
    MM = input()
    if MM.lower() in ('end', 'quit'):
        break
    MM = float(MM)
    Results = float(MM/convert)
    print("*****Inches*****")
    print("%.3f" % Results)
    print("%.4f" % Results)
    print("%.5f" % Results)
```

Comment: Yeah I am trying to do something like  if MM=="end" then exit program

Comment: Yes, that's what my first example does? I just made it an extra option to write quit :)

Comment: @user2316617 also, you did `MM=float(input())` which makes it impossible to check `MM=="string"` because `MM` is no longer a string, it's a number.

Comment: According to the docs on [`os._exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit), *"The standard way to exit is `sys.exit(n)`. `_exit()` should normally only be used in the child process after a `fork()`"*, which is not the case here.