# Get Python3 to answer a Y/N Question of an embedded Script with os.system

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I embedded a script (EyeWitness) with os.system into my Python3-Code, which at the End asks "Do you want to see the final report? Y/N", which interrupts the continuing of the script until manual input was made.

So far I put the Script as last Step of my Code, but that doesn't work as final solution.

```
sleeper = 1
domain = google.com


#EyeWitness

print("\n\nGetting EyeWitness from GitHub... \n")
time.sleep(float(sleeper))
os.system("git clone https://github.com/FortyNorthSecurity/EyeWitness.git")
os.system("python ./EyeWitness/EyeWitness.py --jitter 5 -f ./folder/%s/output.txt --web --prepend-https" % domain)
time.sleep(float(sleeper))
```

At the End, the Script Asks a Yes/No Question which i want to be answered "no" by default, so far I'm stuck at manual input

Comment: Doesn't this thread help your case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16215922/4636715 ?

Comment: @vahdet I'm not certain, I'm pretty new to python, but I'll give it a try. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use user input to end a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215922/how-to-use-user-input-to-end-a-program)

Comment: @vahdet Problem was not solved, I just want my script to give out a "Y" to end the request of EyeWitness